# jupyterにおいてcsvがuploadできない

Tags: csv, jupyter-notebook

jupyterで右上のuploadボタンをクリックし、アップロードしたいcsvファイルを選択しても何も反応がありません。解決策はないでしょうか？

現在は、csvファイルをMoveボタンで目的のフォルダに直接置くことで対応しています。
ただし、元のファイル自体が移動してしまい不便な状態です。

Comment: uploadボタンをクリックしたら、各OSのファイルを開くダイアログが表示されるはずです。「アップロードしたいcsvファイルを選択した」後、「開く」、「選択」というボタンをクリックしていますか？それとも、そういうボタンが表示されませんか。

Comment: 同じ現象かわかりませんが、一度アップロードしたファイルを削除し、再度アップロードする時には、ご質問の内容と同じ状況になりました。ブラウザで画面をリロードするとアップロードできるようになりました。

Comment: 開くをクリックした後反応が無い状態です。質問の内容は会社のＰＣで起こっている事象なのですが、家のＰＣでは開く→選択で通常通りアップロードすることができます。

Comment: 環境の問題であれば、jupyter notebookのログやブラウザの開発者ツールのコンソールでエラーが発生していないか確認する必要があると思います。

Comment: Jupyter Notebook は、IE11とEdgeはサポートしていません。会社のPCということであれば、IE11かEdgeを使っていませんか？

Comment: それから会社の場合は、ファイルを持ち出しされないように、ファイルのアップロードにガードをかけている可能性があります。

Comment: 皆様ありがとうございます。職場ではIEを利用していたので、まずはブラウザをの変更で対応してみます。

Answer (score 1):

`Jupyter Notebook`の対応ブラウザーは、`Chrome`, `Safari`,`FireFox`です ([参照](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/notebook.html#browser-compatibility))。それ以外の`IE`や`Edge`を使っている場合は、ブラウザーを対応ブラウザーに変更してみましょう。

`Jupyter Notebook`は、デフォルトブラウザーを起動するようになっていますが、会社ではデフォルトブラウザーを好きなように設定できない場合があります。その場合には、`jupyter_notebook_config.py`で設定する必要があります（[Windowsの場合の参考](https://qiita.com/acknpop/items/4e5b57e38780068a9155)）。

ブラウザーを変更しても改善しない場合は、直接的な解決策ではありませんが、Jupyterではシェルコマンドが使えるのでシェルコマンドでコピーする方法があります。

```
# Linux, Macの場合
!cp path_to_csv/*.csv .
# Windowsの場合
!copy path_to_csv\*.csv .
```

また、Pythonで、次のようにデータをコピするルーチンまで書いておくと最初は少し手間ですが、以後は自動化できます。

```
from pathlib import Path
import shutil

files = Path('path_to_csv').glob('*.csv')
for f in files:
    print(f)
    shutil.copy(f, '.' )
```